# OwnCloud create user from PHP

Tags: php, owncloud

I want to make script to create new user in OwnCloud.
I trying this:

```
$url = "http://admin:password@example.com/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/";

$owncloud_postdata = array(
                'userid' => "testname",
            'password' => "testpassword,
    );
$owncloud_postdataurl = http_build_query($owncloud_postdata);
$init = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $init, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $init, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $init, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $init, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $owncloud_postdataurl );
$owncloud_odpoved = curl_exec( $init );
curl_close($init);
```

I getting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ocs>
 <meta>
  <status>failure</status>
  <statuscode>999</statuscode>
  <message>Invalid query, please check the syntax. API specifications are here: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/open-collaboration-services. DEBUG OUTPUT:
</message>
 </meta>
 <data/>
</ocs>
```

What is wrong with this? I use PHP 5.5, and I need to use only PHP, not JS or other... I cant see anything wrong... Thanks

Comment: 1. Do you really pass user and password as part of the url? everybody listening to your conversation may read user and password information directly... 2. Did you follow the link in the response?

Comment: 1. How I can pass user/password other way?

2. I dont understand the question

Comment: Passing user/password as part of the Url is usually a very insecure way. Please consult your API documentation if there are any other way (especially as you are passing username and passwort as part of the POST data as well). The link I refer to is http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/open-collaboration-services. Another point, passing POST data remains unsecure as well as long as `http` is used instead of `https`

Comment: There is  a doc to API: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/configuration_user/user_provisioning_api.html

Yes, I follow it and I dont get any help on the link

Answer (score 0):

I found [the API docs](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/next/developer_manual/core/apis/provisioning-api.html#instruction-set-for-users) and was wondering why I was getting the 999 error. Turns out it occurs when the Provisioning API is disabled. To enable it go as admin to Settings > Apps > Show disabled Apps and activate it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$owncloud_postdata = array(
            'userid' => "testname",
        'password' => "testpassword,
);
```

should be

```
$owncloud_postdata = array(
            'userid' => "testname",
        'password' => "testpassword
);
```